# Log Liferay Signin attempts

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm wondering if there is a way to log all sign in attempts in Liferay 6.2. My goal is to monitor all login attempts (successfull and failure) so I can build an ELK dashboard and see if there is a sudden peak in e.g. faild login attemts - maybe because some kind of bot is penetrating my website.

So far I didn't find any default setting or function to log all logins with their credentials. I want to see which username tries to sign in as well.

If there are propper pre- and post-login events I can use in a hook that would be fine for me as well. I would take care of the logging tasks myself then. Sadly my attempts so far fell short. I wasn't able to include the credentials in my log string.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such out of the box functionality.

But, as usually in Liferay, you have two options:

- Check the marketplace if there is a plugin for that
- Or create such a plugin yourself

There is a plugin in the marketplace that could fit your needs: [Audit EE](https://www.liferay.com/de/marketplace/-/mp/application/15195165)

I've never used it, so I can't tell you anything about it.

And in case you are not satisfied with the options it offers, here is the *write a plugin yourself solution*:

If you want to log the failed attempts only, you need to implement an `AuthFailure` class:

```
public LogLoginFailures implements AuthFailure {

   public void onFailureByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, 
       Map<String, String[]> headerMap, 
       Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
     MyLoginLogUtil.logFailure(emailAddress);
   }

   // Implement the two other onFailure... methods the same way

}
```

You will need to write the `MyLoginLogUtil` by yourself. You could use a Liferay service which you would create with the *Liferay Service Builder*.

To declare your `AuthFailure` instance you just need to add it in your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
auth.failure=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LoginFailure,...LogLoginFailures
```

The property stores a list of handlers. You should keep the default `LoginFailure` to have the default behavior of storing the last failed login attempt per user.

If you really want to log *all* sign in attempts, you can add a `Authenticator` in the `auth.pipeline.post` property in your portal-ext.properties:

```
public LogLoginFailures implements AuthFailure {

  public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, 
      String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, 
      Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
     MyLoginLogUtil.logSuccesss(emailAddress);
     return SUCCESS;
   }

   // Implement the two other authenticate... methods the same way

}
```

That will log the succeeded login attempts.

You could add an Authenticator as first handler in the `auth.pipeline.pre` property as well, but that wouldn't be able to distinguish between failed and succeeded logins.

Comment: Just a note - we have used the audit EE plugin with a custom Audit EE hook for tracking when a page layout changed. The same approach could work for login audit as well